# hey guys, can anyone explain this piece of code to me?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, for-of-loop

i'm currently learning JavaScript and have to do this challenge for one of the coding challenges and the challenge is :
"Create an object called 'scorers' which contains the name of the players who scored as properties and the number of goals as the value. in this game it will look like this:
{
Gnarby: 1,
Hummels: 1,
Lewandowski: 2
}"
the solution :
"loop over the array, and add the array elements as object properties,
and then increase the count as we encounter a new occurrence of a certain element"

the object :

```
const game = {
 scored: ['Lewandowski', 'Gnarby', 'Lewandowski', 'Hummels']
};
```

the solution is :

```
const scorers = {};
for (const player of game.scored) {
  scorers[player] ? scorers[player]++ : (scorers[player] = 1);
}
```

and the outcome is :

```
[Lewandowski: 2, Gnarby: 1, Hummels: 1]
```

i don't understand exactly what happens at the **scorers[player] ? scorers[player]++ : (scorers[player] = 1);**
what the scorers[player]++ do ?

Comment: You might benefit from stepping though the code with a debugger to see how it's working...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a ternary operator that checks whether `game` contains the value of `player` as a property. If so, it increments the value of that property. Otherwise, it sets it to `1`.

It can also be rewritten like so:

```js
if(scorers[player]){
    scorers[player]++;
} else {
    scorers[player] = 1;
}
```

If `scorers` does not have the value of `player` as a property, `scorers[player]` will return undefined, which, when coerced to a boolean, is `false`.

Comment: thx for the respons and sry for my lack of knowledge of this matter as i'm new to the Javascript. but where does the ternary operator checks if the game contains the value of player as a property, to me it just checks the scorer[player].

i don't understand the scorers[player] check and its relation to the game object.

Comment: thank you @Spectric, i understand it now. i was looking for the only time that the scorers[player] would return true and didn't thought about the condition being false.